# input:checked ~ div.submenu Android browser 4.4.2

Tags: android, css

The following code is not working on Android browser vers. 4.4.2

HTML

```
<ul><li>
       <input id="check-1" type="checkbox" name="menu"/>
       <label for="check-1">☰</label>
       <div class="submenu">content</div>
    </li></ul>
```

CSS

```
input:checked ~ div.submenu{
  min-height:200vh;
  height:auto;
  transition:max-height 0.5s ease-in;
  z-index:9999;
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
```

the full code here https://jsfiddle.net/erickb/3tsbp752/
Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you explain "not working"? where is your html? what do you get/not get?

Comment: :checked + or  ~  is not working  to do anything , no matter what

Comment: and what about your html?

Comment: According to MDN both `:checked` and `+/~` selectors work in android mobile >=2.1, so I don't see any reason for this to not work. If you can create a working example (jsfiddle) it will be great

Comment: but it doesn't work at all, it works perfectly for Chrome Safari Firefox Opera and IE lasts versions

http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/mobile.html

Comment: Provide and example of a code that works on chrome and doesn't work on android

Comment: the provided code  doesnt work on android browser

Comment: Do you know what exact (minor) version of the android browser you are using? (4.X?)

Comment: Android Browser V 4.4.2

Comment: Can you check if this works on your android browser: https://jsfiddle.net/3bgLsjkz/3/ ?

Comment: It is checked / unchecked but the div is not displayed
 the full example here https://jsfiddle.net/erickb/3tsbp752/  not working  on Android browser 4.4.2

Comment: Did you check the link I gave?

Comment: yes, as I said it doesn't work,  checked unchecked works but not :checked + or   :checked ~

Comment: If you check the example there is no `:checked` there. My guess is that it's related to the `200vh`, however it should be working on android browser >=4.2 (and you are using 4.4)

Comment: change vh and vw value for % or px it will be the same , it doesn't work, 
I mean my code is not working, the goal is ti display a submenu without js

Comment: Checked with `200px` and it works perfect on android 4.3 :) https://jsfiddle.net/3bgLsjkz/4/ Check this link, and if it works it means that 4.4 still have some problems with `vh`

Comment: sorry but I don't get what you are trying to do
I want to show hide a submenu as shown in the first post, and I have provided a  link with the full code  jsfiddle.net/erickb/3tsbp752

Comment: In both links (https://jsfiddle.net/3bgLsjkz/3/ and https://jsfiddle.net/3bgLsjkz/4/) there is a red-block (10px width). You don't need to check the input. It is just there (open the links in chrome and then open them in the android browser). If you don't see it in the android browser - your `:checked` version will not work either. Let me know if you see the red block in both versions using android browser.

Comment: I see the red block

Comment: Dekel  sorry for your time, I cannot solve it for old Android browser so I have added a jquery for old versions + IE 9

,it works , 

many thanks

Comment: Did you see the red block in both versions? Anyway, glad I could help (a bit). You are welcome to check my other answer and vote a few if you would like to :)

Comment: yes the red block works but not for hide/show a div 
where can i Vote for you ?

Comment: You can check my answers in my profile :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/5037551/dekel?tab=profile (don't vote too many, otherwise these votes are deleted automatically)

Answer (score 0):

no solved directly with CSS , jquery added for old browsers

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('change', 'input[id="check-menu"]', function (e) { 
    if($('#check-menu').prop('checked')) {
      $('#submenu-main').addClass('old-show');
    } else {
      $('#submenu-main').removeClass('old-show');
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: It will be nice to see a complete solution